# pip install and python setup.py behave differently

Tags: pip

I have a setup.py that compiles some c code using gcc. It then installs the binary.

When using python setup.py install, the binary runs just fine.

When using pip install for this package, I get

```
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.0' not found
```

Does anyone know why this is the case and how I can work around this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I actually have the reverse problem. Is this a publicly available package?